# Overriding Mage_Customer_AccountController and adding a custom function?

Tags: overrides, controllers

I am overriding the forgotPasswordPostAction function in Mage_Customer_AccountController. This works well, I can call the function with a URL like that:

http://domain.com/whatever/index.php/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/

Now I added a testAction function to the same controller, but I cant call it by URL, I always get forwarded to the login page (http://domain.com/whatever/index.php/customer/account/login/). Why? Can I define exceptions from that behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: you added `testAction` in your module's controller.Please provide your controller file for reference ?

Comment: share your code which you tried

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the `preDispatch` method in the `AccountController`.

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    [...]    
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $openActions = array(
        'create',
        'login',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation'
    );
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}
```

If you add your test method to the `$openActions` array it will be allowed. Now it gets redirected to login as stated in the `if-else`